# Logical Operators (AND Operators)

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I came across the following logical operators workaround but could not comprehend the logic behind:

`console.log(1 && 2)` will get you `2`

`console.log(false && X)` will get you `false`

`console.log(true && X)` will get you `UncaughtReferenceError:X is not defined`

Anyone can explain the answer?

Comment: I found this video tutorial very helpful in understanding logical operators, may help you too:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHpLGco_jSk&list=PLaZSdijfCCJDm33pC1WX56jTW1r9Ln1EG&index=20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) for the `&&` operator:

> **&&**; Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

In the first example, you provide the numbers 1 and 2 as the operands. 1 cannot be converted to `false`, therefore the second operand, which happens to be 2, is returned.

The two last examples are fairly straightforward, as booleans are involved. If either operand is false, you get back `false`. The reason only the third one gives you an error is because in the second, the second operand (`X`) is never checked due to short-circuiting. Short-circuiting means that once JS sees that the first value is `false`, it does not even bother to check the other value. JS sees `false` as the first operand and immediately returns.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, there are truthy and falsy values. The falsy values are

- `false`
- `0` (the number zero),
- `""` or `''` (the empty string),
- `undefined` and `null`.

All other values are truthy.

This is how the `&&` operator works *in JavaScript*:

1. Evaluate the first operand. If the result is a falsy value, return that value.
2. Otherwise, evaluate the second operand and return its value.

Let's take a look at your examples:

- The `1` in `1 && 2` is truthy, so `2` is evaluated and returned as the value of the expression.
- The `false` in `false && X` is falsy, so it is returned as the value of the expression. The second operand (`X`) will not be evaluated.
- The `true` in `true && X` is truthy, so the second operand is evaluated, which throws an error, because there is no `X`.

This behavior is very useful if you want to have a fallback value:

```js
function logName (options) {
  const name = options.name || 'Default name';
  console.log(name);
}

logName({ name: 'foo' }); // logs 'foo'
logName({ name: '' });    // logs 'Default name'
logName({});              // logs 'Default name'
```

Answer (score 1):

So consider the following statement: `A && B`. What the `&&` operator does here is return `A` *only* if its value is `false` otherwise it returns `B`. That’s how the AND operator works in JavaScript and most other languages for that matter.

So this explains the first 2 lines of code. In the third line, the statement should return the `B` variable which is `X` in here. However `X` seems to be an undeclared variable so the console raises an error.